# How do I find and remove duplicate lines from a file using Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex

This question is meant to be language agnostic. Using only Regular Expressions, can I find and replace duplicate lines in a file?

Please consider the follwing example input and the output that I want;

Input>>

```
11
22
22  <-duplicate
33
44
44  <-duplicate
55
```

Output>>

```
11
22
33
44
55
```

Comment: Regular expressions are executed by some program (SED, PERL, PYTHON, JAVA, something).  The "not use any programming language" doesn't make any sense.  What program runs the regular expression?

Comment: Yes, and besides what S.Lott said, you have to specify better what do you mean by "remove". Remove all occurrences of duplicate lines? Or remove all-but-one? If the latter, which one would you like to preserve, the first or the last? Or the order doesn't matter?

Comment: And finally, should run in a single pass, or multiple passes are allowed?

Comment: @ebattulga: I agree with others. You cannot ask a regular expression question that is language agnostic. The underlying regex engine matters greatly.

Comment: I use regex search and replace in Notepad2 and Programmer's Notepad.. I'm sure others exist. I think his question is valid.

Comment: If you don't know which program - just guess Perl. :-)  Everything else tries to copy that.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Regular-expressions.info has a page on [Deleting Duplicate Lines From a File](http://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html)

This basically boils down to searching for this oneliner:

```
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

... And replacing with `\1`.
<sub>Note: Dot must not match Newline</sub>

Explanation:

> The [caret](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) will match only at the start of a line. So the regex engine will only attempt to match the remainder of the regex there. The [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) and [star](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) combination simply matches an entire line, whatever its contents, if any. The parentheses store the matched line into the first backreference.
>
> Next we will match the line separator. I put the [question mark](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) into `\r?\n` to make this regex work with both Windows (`\r\n`) and UNIX (`\n`) text files. So up to this point we matched a line and the following line break.
>
> Now we need to check if this combination is followed by a duplicate of that same line. We do this simply with `\1`. This is the first backreference which holds the line we matched. The backreference will match that very same text.
>
> If the backreference fails to match, the regex match and the backreference are discarded, and the regex engine tries again at the start of the next line. If the backreference succeeds, the [plus symbol](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) in the regular expression will try to match additional copies of the line. Finally, the [dollar symbol](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) forces the regex engine to check if the text matched by the backreference is a complete line. We already know the text matched by the backreference is preceded by a line break (matched by \r?\n). Therefore, we now check if it is also followed by a line break or if it is at the end of the file using the [dollar sign](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
>
> The entire match becomes `line\nline` (or `line\nline\nline` etc.). Because we are doing a search and replace, the line, its duplicates, and the line breaks in between them, are all deleted from the file. Since we want to keep the original line, but not the duplicates, we use `\1` as the replacement text to put the original line back in.

Comment: In Notepad++ I did the following, which is the same thing except it removes duplicates that aren't adjacent as well (that's a non-capture group in the middle there): `^(.*)$((?:\r?\n.*)*?)^\1$\r?\n?` replaced with `$1$2` Seems to be working well.

Comment: This worked perfectly in VS code. To delete the duplicates in search/replace, you need to use `$2` as the replace value. This will delete all the duplicates.

Comment: Wow this is black magic indeed. Just a question though since I did not understand it perfectly, why do we need the last $ thingy? Oh I now get it. This is so that we don't mistakenly replace a line which has a part of our search. Like if we have a line `hello...44...hello`, we don't want to replace this since this is not a duplicate of a line that only has `44`. Correct me if I am wrong though. Thanks

Comment: Here I am again, 1.5 years later, using my own comment. By the way, if you want to remove all duplicates entirely (including the originals), just replace with `$2`.

Comment: In my case, it could be duplicate, "triplicate" and so on, so, in vim, I run with success ```%s/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+/\1/cg```

Comment: in PHP, I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613069/6614155

Comment: It's worth mentioning prominently that the regex only works if the duplicates are ordered.

Comment: If you wish to find duplicate lines that may or may not have 1 or more empty lines between them, then this should work: `^(.*)[\r\n]*(\r?\n\1)+$`

Comment: To accept NON ADJASCENT: `^(.*)((\r?\n.*)+\1)+$`

Answer (score 6):

See my request for more info, I'm answering in the *easy way* now.

1. If the order doesn't matter, just a

   sort -u

   will do the trick
2. If the order does matter but you don't mind re-run multiple passes (this is vim syntax), you can use:

   %s/\(.*\)\(\_.*\)\(\1\)/\2\1/g

   to preserve the last occurrence, or

   %s/\(.*\)\(\_.*\)\(\1\)/\1\2/g

   to preserve the first occurrence.

If you do mind re-run multiple passes, than it's more difficult, so before we work on that, please say so in the question!

EDIT: in your edit you weren't very clear, but it looks like you want just a single-pass duplicate ADJACENT lines removal! Well, that's much easier!

A simple:

```
/(.*)\1*/\1/
```

(`/\(.*\)\1*/\1/` in vim) i.e. searching for `(.*)\1*` and replacing it with just `\1` will do the trick

Comment: `(.*)\1*` does not match duplicate lines because there's nothing in your regex that matches the line break between the line and its duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

In RegexBuddy you can do this as follows:

1. On the Library tab, load the RegexBuddy.rbl library if not loaded by default.
2. In the lookup box, type "duplicate"
3. Click the Use button to load the "delete duplicate lines" regex.
4. On the GREP tab, specify the folder and file mask of the files you want to delete duplicates from.
5. In the drop-down menu of the GREP button, select Execute.

If you're only doing this on one file, you can use the Test tab instead of the GREP tab.  Load the file on the Test tab, and then click the Replace button in the main toolbar.