# Remove last repeated word occurence in a string PHP

Tags: php

I need remove last repeated word in a string, example:

Last repeat word is: `all/`

String input examples:

- `item1/item2/all/`
- `item1/item2/all/all/all/`
- `item1/item2/all/all/all/all/`

The result should be always: `item1/item2/`

Comment: Is this "last repeated word" known in advance, or do you have to dynamically figure out what the last repeated word is?

Comment: check the similar [quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613063/remove-duplicate-from-string-in-php) has already been answered.

Answer (score 5):

If those "words" are always separated by slash, then it's as simple as a regex with a backreference:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\b(\w+/)\1+$#', '', $str);
           //  here \b could be written as (?<=/) more exactly
```

Or if `all` is a fixed string to look for:

```
$str = preg_replace('#/(all/)+$#', '/', $str);
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution, I really need to learn regular expressions, except it doesn't work for the first example. A simple fix I assume.

Comment: True. If the searched word is fixed, then `all` could replace `\w+`. And if it doesn't need to be repeated actually, then `\1*` instead of `\1+` would do. Not sure about OPs use case (looks like path names somewhat).

Comment: why did you wrote `#\b(` and not `#/(`

Comment: @yes123: Both would work I believe. The `/` however only if there are preceeding path fragments, like in that exact example. But of course matching `/` and then adding `'/'` again as replacement would be an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want the last word removed, and any repeats of it

```
$list = explode('/', $str);
if(end($list) == '') array_pop($list); // remove empty entry on end
$last = array_pop($list);
while(end($list) == $last) array_pop($list);
$str = implode('/', $list); // put back together
```