# PHP: Get union of a string

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove duplicate from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613063/remove-duplicate-from-string-in-php)

Have a string like:

```
$str = "1 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 1 - 4 - 3 - 1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 4";
```

and i need to get

```
$str = "1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6";
```

any help.. :(

Comment: I've downvoted, as it is much better to explain what you've tried, ideally with a code sample. Sitting down with a manual and giving things a go _first_ is the best way to learn `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had a quick look around and with the code from

- [remove duplicate from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613063/remove-duplicate-from-string-in-php)

  ```
  $str = implode(' - ',array_unique(explode(' - ', $string )));
  ```

This would work for you.

You can see [a demo of the example](http://codepad.org/CtLyxF9K).

Answer (score 5):

Example/[Demo](http://codepad.org/4tAK3MDo):

```
$elements = array_unique(explode(' - ', $input));
sort($elements);
$str = implode(' - ', $elements);
```

Comment: Ah sorted as well, good spot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$str = str_replace(' - ', ',', $str);
$items = array_unique(explode(',', $str));
echo implode(' - ', $items);
?>
```

I've swapped the space-hifen-space delimiter so you can see what's going on in intermediate steps - but you can explode on that immediately if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make new string with unique values you would try this:

```
implode(' - ', array_unique(explode(' - ', $array)));
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I would do something like this:

```
$strArray = explode(' - ',$str);
str = array_unique($strArray);
```

Or something to that effect.

Comment: errr, you probably want to implode that back to $str :P