# PHP remove (conditional) duplicate row in text

Tags: php, duplicates

```
$string = "Apple
Foo
Banana
...
Banana
Foo
Other text
...
Apple";
```

I have text where single rows are duplicated after a row "...".

The rows before and after that can be anything ("Foo"), but also be a duplicate (without "..." like "Apple").

The "..."-row can appear multiple times without a duplicate row after it.

I only want to remove duplicated rows which have a "..." row inbetween.

In other words: Remove the line after "..." if it's the same as above "..."

How can I match

```
Banana
...
Banana
```

to remove the duplicated row:

```
Banana
```

so the result is

```
$string = "Apple
Foo
Banana
...
Foo
Other text
...
Apple";
```

Cheers!

Comment: what have you done 'till now? Have you any code to start from?

Comment: `Foo` still appears twice though

Comment: No chance here now any more, I knew people who love `What have you tried` will come soon, nothing to learn anything for you here these days.

Comment: Do you want to remove anything that is repeated after a "..." row? Like or does the copy have to directly above and below it? Do the repeats only show up after a "..." row?

Comment: The line with ... and the next line should be removed? Is that it?

Comment: Only the line after "..." if it's the same as above "..."

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove duplicate from string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613063/remove-duplicate-from-string-in-php)

Comment: No dupe since `array_unique()` doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the task is to just remove the line following the line with three dots:

```
echo preg_replace("/^(.+?)\r?\n(\.{3})\r?\n\\1/m", "\\1\n\\2", $string);
```

The expression matches:

- a whole line comprising at least one character (1)
- three dots on a single line (2)
- a whole line comprising at least one character (1)

The `/m` modifier is used to select multi-line mode, in which `^` and `$` carry the meaning of start and end of the line.

The `\\1` back reference is used to match whatever was before the three dots.

The replacement `'\\1'` is needed to place back the matched line with three dots.

Comment: Edited the answer to place the `...` back into the final string

Comment: I'm sorry, the "..."-row can appear multiple times without dupe rows.

Comment: @Martin saw you chose another answer as accepted. Did my answer not work for you?

Comment: @Martin wow that's really weird, I tested it locally before I posted and it worked but it seems there's spaces after the `...` and before the end-of-line marker ... strange ... updated answer

Comment: @Martin ah, of course, Windows new lines =p the joys of regexp

Comment: Oh! Works now and is much lighter than brute force. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines = explode("\n", $string);  
$uniqueLines = array_unique(lines);
$result = implode("\n", $uniqueLines);
```

Comment: This removes the second `Foo` as well, I think the OP wants something else.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can remove duplicate **lines** in the string:

```
$string = implode( "\n", array_unique( explode( "\n", $string)));
```

[`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) the string into an array on the newline, call [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) on the resulting array, and join the string back together with [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode).

**Output:**

```
Text row A
Foo
Text row B
...
Text row C
```

However, note that the output doesn't perfectly match your desired output, as your desired output conflicts with your definition of the problem.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2MRt7U)

Comment: Sorry my example was not clear enough. I only want to remove duplicated rows which have a "..." row inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand all the conditions (could you have duplicates before the ... for example), but how about `$string = implode("\n", array_unique(explode("\n", $string)));`

**Update**
Brute force solution:

```
$string = "Apple\nFoo\nBanana\n...\nBanana\nFoo\nOther text\n...\nApple\n";
$string2 = "";

$arr = explode("\n", $string);

$string2 .= $arr[0] . "\n";
$string2 .= $arr[1] . "\n";

for ($i=2; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{
    if ($arr[$i-1] != '...' || $arr[$i-2] != $arr[$i])
    {
        $string2 .= $arr[$i] . "\n";
    }

}

echo $string2;
```

Comment: Updated with a brute force solution (though I'm sure there's a neat RegExp way to solve this)

Comment: Welcome! You should probably check that the `explode` returns two items before blindly appending them to the string. Otherwise you'll get some funky results if the input string is empty (or doesn't contain newlines).