# Delete duplicate content in string with PHP

Tags: php, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove duplicate from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613063/remove-duplicate-from-string-in-php)

How to detect and remove duplicate content ignoring recurring `"\n"`-s with PHP?

I have the following string:

> \nrazor989\nalcatraz\nartez\ntajemniczyxd\nmrrazor\nqwertyuiop\npomroczny4\nomgdmg\ngreat_jojek\nmaciekcz242\nkaka2610\nteleskop1\nsupciokawa\nklocek18\nkacpi999\npawel1909\npozbierany\nkelthuzan\nistrim\ngroch\nmario\nalcatraz\n

Comment: What is the desired output?  For example, do you want an array consisting of ['razor989', 'alcatraz', 'artez', ...]?

Answer (score 4):

Please try

```
$str = 'your string';
$ar = explode('\n', $str);
$ar = array_unique($ar);
echo implode('\n', $ar); //edited - original code had $arr
```

Comment: It fails hard. $arr is not defined, if changed to "$ar" it does nothing

Comment: Yes in 4th line should be echo implode('\n', $ar);

Answer (score 2):

Make it a unique array:

```
$massiveString = '\nrazor989\nalcatraz\nartez\ntajemniczyxd\nmrrazor\nqwertyuiop\npomroczny4\nomgdmg\ngreat_jojek\nmaciekcz242\nkaka2610\nteleskop1\nsupciokawa\nklocek18\nkacpi999\npawel1909\npozbierany\nkelthuzan\nistrim\ngroch\nmario\nalcatraz\n';

echo implode('\n', array_unique(explode('\n', $massiveString)));
```

Comment: It works but if I put $massiveString = $mystring; it fails, why?

Comment: Replace `$massiveString` with `$mystring`