# Array_Unique filtering

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an multidimensional array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [MTime_Id] => 1
            [MName] => Breakfast
            [DName] => Other Cereals
            [IName] => 
            [Date] => 2013-02-05
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [MTime_Id] => 1
        [MName] => Breakfast
        [DName] => Porridge
        [IName] => Oats,Milk,Sugar
        [Date] => 2013-02-06
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [MTime_Id] => 1
        [MName] => Breakfast
        [DName] => Porridge
        [IName] => Oats,Milk,Sugar,Oats,Milk,Sugar
        [Date] => 2013-02-05
    )
```

)

And I am trying to use array unique to filter this

```
 [IName] => Oats,Milk,Sugar,Oats,Milk,Sugar
```

I am having no luck. How can I filter the duplicates?

Cheers.

Comment: WShat are you trying to get?? The last element IName?? I dont understand your question.

Comment: What duplicates?  How do you know that's a duplicate?

Comment: In the second element, I am trying to remove the duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filter input and therefore don't have extra spaces in `IName` field, you can use something as simple as this for filtering:

```
$array[2]['IName'] = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $array[2]['IName'])));
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I was using a foreach before, for some reason it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you habe in array two Oats,Milk,Sugar as element of IName, in array three you have Oats,Milk,Sugar,Oats,Milk,Sugar. This is not the same!

"Oats,Milk,Sugar"=="Oats,Milk,Sugar,Oats,Milk,Sugar" (or "Oats,Milk,Sugar".equals("Oats,Milk,Sugar,Oats,Milk,Sugar")) is false.

If you want to have it unique you have to explode the single results and then do a unique on it or you have to store the single values in seperate fields...

BTW: Here is a link how to remove duplicates from a multi dimensional array [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613063/remove-duplicate-from-string-in-php I think this is what I am trying to do, but the code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a function exists for that, here is a simple solution,
you can loop the array, and get the result of each value, then explode result, and insert it into an array.
then use the array_unique function.
try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($arrays as $array)
{
    $tmp = $array['IName'];
    $tmp2 = explode(',',$tmp);
    foreach ($tmp2 as $t)
    {
        $result[]=$t;
    }
}
$array_unique = array_unique($result);
```