# Filter array or string(removing some words)

Tags: php

My problem is not very complex but I can't find a solution yet. I have a string:

```
$temp_string = '20938999038,0.5,83888999289,0.5,98883888778,0.9';

// Meaning syskey, price, syskey, price, syskey, price
```

I want to remove price and show only syskey.

My desirable result:

```
 '20938999038,83888999289,98883888778'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you hurting yourself and you're not using arrays instead?

Comment: Use `explode()` and work with array.

Comment: You need to enclose your string in quotes, otherwise it's not a string.  Also have a look at [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode), they should point you in the right direction.

Comment: $parts=explode(",",$temp_string);

Comment: Thanks for quick answers as long as I got desired results.every solution is welcome.

Comment: Don't forget to select the correct solution that best applies to your situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove duplicate from string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613063/remove-duplicate-from-string-in-php)

Comment: this is not a duplicate case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
$string = "20938999038,0.5,83888999289,0.5,98883888778,0.9";

$new = array();
foreach(explode(",", $string) as $k => $v) {
    $k % 2 or $new[] = $v;
}
echo implode(",", $new); // 20938999038,83888999289,98883888778
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `explode` it by delimiter

```
$explode = explode(",", $temp_string);
unset($explode[1], $explode[3], $explode[5]);
```

Assuming your string always follows this pattern.

Comment: Thanks.What if for longer or shorter inputs?

Comment: Well if it follows the same pattern you could continue to add to the `unset` command. Probably the best solution if it is every other is to do what @Baba recommended and select what values to store based on `mod` in a loop.