# Get all unique file names

Tags: java, regex

To preface, I am a beginner with regex. I have a string that looks something like:

```
     my_folder/foo.xml::someextracontent
     my_folder/foo.xml::someextracontent
     another_folder/foo.xml::someextracontent
     my_folder/bar.xml::someextracontent
     my_folder/bar.xml::someextracontent
     my_folder/hello.xml::someextracontent
```

I want to return unique XML files which are part of `my_folder`. So the regex will return:

```
my_folder/foo.xml
my_folder/bar.xml
my_folder/hello.xml
```

I've taken a look at [Extract All Unique Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734796/extract-all-unique-lines) which is close to what I need but I am not sure where to go from there.

The closest attempt I got was `(?sm)(my_folder\/.*?.xml)(?=.*\1)` which gets all the duplicates but I want the opposite, so I tried doing a negative lookahead instead `(?sm)(my_folder\/.*?.xml)(?!.*\1)` but the capture groups are totally wrong.

What am I missing here in my regex? Here's link to the regex: https://regex101.com/r/ggY2RB/1

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good question, although such a task might be better done with `uniq` or another utility. Would you be open to non-regex solutions?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately this is done in java so I can’t do that. I’ve updated the tags to reflect this. I was just wondering if there’s a solution using regex only. Otherwise I can just grab all file names and throw them in a Set

Comment: If you're using Java, just use a `HashSet`. I bet it's faster than regex.

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/ruKpsw/4) might help you to find the unique strings that you might be looking for:

```
/(\w+\/\w+\.xml)(?![\s\S]*\1)/s
```

[image]

If you only wish to match `my_folder`, you might try [this](https://regex101.com/r/ruKpsw/5):

```
 /(\my_folder\/\w+\.xml)(?![\s\S]*\1)/s
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a positive lookahead `(?=`, to get the unique strings you could use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert what is on the right is not what you have captured in group 1.

In your pattern you are using making the dot match a newline using `(?s)`and use a non greedy dot start `.*?` but you might also use a negated character class matching not a newline or a forward slash.

If the folder can also contain nested folders, you might use a pattern that repeats 0+ times 1+ whitespace chars followed by a forward slash.

```
(?s)(my_folder/(?:[^/\n]+/)*[^/\n]+\.xml)::(?!.*\1)
```

- `(?s)`
- `(` Capture group

  - `my_folder/` Match literally
  - `(?:[^/\n]+/)*` Repeat 0+ times not a forward slash or a newline followed by a forward slash
  - `[^/\n]+\.xml` Match 1+ ot a forward slash or a newline followed by .xml
- `)` Close capture group
- `::(?!.*\1)` Match `::` followed by asserting what is on the right does not contain what is captured in group 1

In Java

```
String regex = "(?s)(my_folder/(?:[^/\\n]+/)*[^/\\n]+\\.xml)::(?!.*\\1)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDo4v8/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/683qTq)

Comment: Thanks, then how come `(?sm)(my_folder\/.*?.xml)(?!.*\1)` doesn't work? The capture group gets all the XML file names, and then the negative lookahead should exclude the match if it matches `.*\1` right?

My assumption was like `my_folder/test.xml::helloworld my_folder/test.xml` should've been excluded, but instead it included all of it in the capture group

Comment: That is due to the non greedy dot star `.*?` If it can not match it will give up positions until there is a match.