# Visual Studio Code Find/replace - save with name

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, find-replace

More than often I find that I need some custom regex for me in visual studio code.

Every time I use stackoverflow search to find the same regex rather than trying to rewrite it again and again. Now I am having a separate text note only for that purpose which contains my find/replace regex values. 
e.g.[remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992493/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-in-visual-studio-code)

Is there a custom smart plugin or option which allows me to add find / replace and give them names and save them (similar to ultra edit) directly in Visual Studio Code?

If there is a way to do the same in Visual Studio instead of code I am fine with it as well - I just need to be able to do find replaces quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three extensions that can help you:

[Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#review-details) - which I wrote

[replace rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules)

[regreplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DomiR.regreplace)

They allow you to store and run (either singly or all on save) a list of regexp's find and replaces.

An example setting (in `settings.json`) from Find and Replace:

```
"findInCurrentFile": { 

  "addClassToElement": {
    "title": "Add Class to Html Element",   // will appear in the Command Palette
    "find": ">",
    "replace": " class=\"@\">",
    "restrictFind": "selections",
    "cursorMoveSelect": "@"   // after the replacement, move to and select this text
  }
}
```

An example keybinding(in `keybindings.json`) from Find and Replace:

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",     // note no setting command here
  "args": {
    
    "find": "^([ \\t]*const\\s*)(\\w*)",   // note the double escaping
    
    "replace": "$1\\U$2",                  // capitalize the word following "const"
    "isRegex": true,
    
    "restrictFind": "selections"           // find only in selections
  }
}
```

So you can save a find/replace or a search across files as a named setting or a keybinding.

Comment: Do they allow automatic transfer from the find/replace dialog in VSCode, or does one have to copy/paste the expressions?

Comment: Do you mean if you already have a find and a replace text in the Find Widget, do you have to copy those values into a setting or keybinding like used above?

Comment: Yes, I am surprised that VSCode doesn't have this feature of remembering complex regex find/replace (Notepad++ has it for a long time I think).