# Delete duplicate multiple lines using vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

i have so many line just like this json code (120000 lines)

```
{
"name":"V83.9",
"name":"Work",
"name":"V83.9",
"name":"Education",
"name":"V83.9",
"name":"Profession"
}
```

and i want this convert just like this

```
{
"name":"V83.9",
"name":"Work",
"name":"Education",
"name":"Profession"
}
```

and i wrote regex on vscode just like this but this is not working

Find: `{\n"name":"$1",\n"name":"$2",\n"name":"$1",\n"name":"$3",\n"name":"$1",\n"name":"$4"\n}`

Replace: `{\n"name":"$1",\n"name":"$2",\n"name":"$3",\n"name":"$4"\n}`

How do i do this?

Comment: it's a duplicate question.. please take a look @ the below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992493/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @MichelHanna then can you fix this solution? this duplicate question not fix my solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate lines in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992493/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Are lines 3 and 5 always duplicates of line 1?

Answer (score 4):

Please check the [Transformer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dakara.transformer) extension, where i have applied it on your example and it works: