# How to delete all duplicates in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know how to get rid of all duplicates leaving one line behind like going from;

```
abc
123
123
abc
```

to

```
abc 
123
```

What I want to know is if there's a quick and easy way to get rid of all lines that have duplicates, as in going from;

```
abc
123
123
abc
efg
456
```

to

```
efg 
456
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit: I'm looking for a way to remove all duplicates including the original line, i.e. if 'abc' is present on two lines it removes both instances and not just one. The other question that has been linked as an answer doesn't answer this question

Comment: a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992493/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-lines-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: No, what i'm looking for is a quick and easy way to get rid of all duplicates as well as the original. So if 'abc' is on multiple lines it removes all lines with 'abc' leaving no instances of 'abc' behind