# Regex, removing duplicate non interrupted strings

Tags: regex, string, text, duplicates

I recently tried making a regex for deleting strings which stand after each other without being interrupted by an other string, and then let only one string stay. My work so far : https://regex101.com/r/Cs0bmY/7 . It should work with all possible urls which maybe dont have www. before them or an other ending like .com or .nl etc
The strings (list of urls) looks like this:

```
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
operator.livrareflori.md
amazon.de
fonts.gstatic.com
fonts.gstatic.com
fonts.gstatic.com
erovoyeurism.net
tugtechnologyandbusiness.com
```

The end result should look like this:

```
operator.livrareflori.md
amazon.de
fonts.gstatic.com
erovoyeurism.net
tugtechnologyandbusiness.com
```

You can see that the duplicate strings which are not interrupted by an other string are gone and only 1 result stays.

Comment: Waht language/tool are you using? What did you try? What didn't work? What did you get?

Comment: You may use [`^((?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?\S+\.\S+)\n(?=\1$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Cs0bmY/9)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [• Removing duplicate rows in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad) or [• How do I find and remove duplicate lines from a file using Regular Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573361/how-do-i-find-and-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file-using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You can match

```
^(.+)$(?:\n\1)+
```

thus capturing the first line, and matching subsequent duplicate lines, and then replace everything matched with the first capture group:

```
\1
```

(or the equivalent keyword for the first group in whatever environment you're in)

https://regex101.com/r/Cs0bmY/8

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)$(?:\R\1)+`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^(.+)$      : group 1, a whole line
(?:         : non capture group
    \R      : any kind of line break
    \1      : backreference to group 1
)+          : group must appear 1 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
operator.livrareflori.md
amazon.de
fonts.gstatic.com
erovoyeurism.net
tugtechnologyandbusiness.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to capture the line and use a lookahead to verify that it exists later in the subject. This expression matches duplicates, and substituting with "" makes it keep the last occurrences:

```
(?s)^((?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?\S+\.\S+)\n(?=.*^\1$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Cs0bmY/10

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?\S+\.\S+)\s(?=[\s\S]*\1)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/Cs0bmY/11