# How to delete duplicate lines in a list using Regular Expression in python

Tags: python, regex, list

Is there any way to remove duplicates in a list through Regular expression
If we have duplicates in it. without using set operation

```
["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]
```

I want output as

```
["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Why a regular expression?

Comment: Why you are opting for regular expression when we have  efficient data structure already in place?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `set()`?

Comment: We are using our own framework which will support RE operations only

Comment: `set` is a Python built-in. If you don't have access to `set`, you're not even using a standard Python variant (with or without standard library).

Answer (score 0):

As many of the comments have said, `set()` is probably what you want in python.

```
set(["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"])

>> ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]
```

If you really need to use a regex, use the `re` package along with a regex solution, such as [How do I find and remove duplicate lines from a file using Regular Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573361/how-do-i-find-and-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file-using-regular-expressions)