# Is there an easy way to delete a line of code in M-file that merges the previous and next lines? I do not want any empty line after deletion

Tags: matlab

For instance:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

When I delete line 2, I want my code to automatically look like below:

```
line 1
line 3
```

Note: I am a macOS user.

Note 2: It is M-file.

Comment: "A line of code" -- so you want to edit an M-file on disk? Or are we talking about a string in memory, or text stored in some other way? Please be explicit.

Comment: It is 'M-file on disk'.

Comment: Have you considered  to use regexp? [e.g. this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573361/how-do-i-find-and-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-file-using-regular-expressions) which you should be able to extend to your problem.