# notepad regex delete double alphanumeric string

Tags: notepad++

I would like to delete a row with repeated numbers.

So, for example, if I have a string like this:

```
*imie Małgorzata numer 000333444 lokalizacja Łuków
imie Ola numer 000333444 lokalizacja Łuków
imie Gosia numer 555444333 lokalizacja Łuków
imie mariusz numer 598418415 lokalizacja Łuków*
```

**The desired result will be:**

```
*imie Małgorzata numer 000333444 lokalizacja Łuków
imie Gosia numer 555444333 lokalizacja Łuków
imie mariusz numer 598418415 lokalizacja Łuków*
```

Comment: I think this is problem is similar to another question. Maybe this answer helps already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573425/15647224

Comment: You added an asterisk on the first line. Is this really what you have?

Comment: no. I don't have

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad delete number double lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72550685/notepad-delete-number-double-lines)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^.*?(\b\d+\b).*\R)^.*?\2.*\R?`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(       # start group 1
  ^       # beginning of line
    .*?     # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    (       # start group 2
        \b      # word boundary
        \d+     # 1 or more digits
        \b      # word boundary
    )       # end group 2
    .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
    \R      # any kind of linebreak
)       # end goup 1
  ^       # beginning of line
    .*?     # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    \2      # backreference to group 2 (i.e. the digits)
    .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
    \R      # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1 (i.e. the first line)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]